# Pagination problem in jqgrid with array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid, pagination

I am facing problem with pagination in jqgrid with array data having 18 records, but the records are not displaying in pages even I specified pagination:true,pager:jQuery('#pager1'). Can you please help me to implement pagination instead of scrolling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
 datatype: "clientSide",
 height: 200,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
    ],
    multiselect: true,
 pagination:true,
  pager:jQuery('#pager1'), 
 rowNum: 10,
 rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
 sortname: 'id',   
 sortorder: 'asc',
 viewrecords: true,
 page: 1,
 loadonce: true,  
 totalpages: 2,   
 totalrecords:18,     
 showpage:true,   
 imgpath: "/themes/default/images",         
 caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
 });
 var mydata = [
 {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
 {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
 {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
 {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
 {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
 {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
 {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
 {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
 {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
 {id:"10",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
 {id:"11",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
 {id:"12",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
 {id:"13",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
 {id:"14",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
 {id:"15",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
 {id:"16",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
 {id:"17",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
 {id:"18",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},

 ];
 for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)   
 jQuery("#list4").addRowData(i+1,mydata[i]);
```

Comment: your question helped my question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You main problem is you should reset `rowNum` after the adding the large number of rows. The line

```
jQuery("#list4").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

at the end of your code will fix the problem. I recommend you to add the line

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

directly after the definition of the jqGrid. You will then have not only data paging, but also data filtering (searching) and refresh (reset filter).

Some more small remarks:

- in the definition of the `mydata` array you should remove ',' before ']'.
- in the for loop you should use `i<mydata.length` instead of `i<=mydata.length`.
- you should remove from the definition of jqGrid following parameters which are either non existent (like `pagination`) or have no sense in the context (like `loadonce: true`): `pagination`, `page`, `loadonce`, `totalpages`, `totalrecords`, `showpage`, `imgpath`.

You receive the best results if you constructs jqGrid with respect of `data: myData` parameter, or set all data from `mydata` at once (see description of `addRowData` method in http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data).

Answer (score 1):

Oleg is correct.
Adding jQuery("#list4").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
works.

Although it might not work if **formatter** property is set where the rowObject values will be undefined.(if they are used)

Therefore make sure in your formatter method u always check for their availability.

e.g.

```
function getFormattedFileName(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

        if(!rowObject.fileName) {// this is due to ...trigger("reloadGrid");
            return cellvalue; // the value is already formatted, let's just return it
        }
 return rowObject.fileName.trim();
}
```