# jqgrid paging - always shows 0 of 1

Tags: jqgrid, paging

I am trying to get paging work on my jqgrid, but it always reads "1 of 0",
I am loading data using addRowData to populate data on my grid.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= mydata1[0].rows.length; i++)
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata1[0].rows[i]);
```

The data returned is in the format:

{total:'1',records:'10',page:'1',rows:[{ 'name': "Beginners Guide to the Stock Market"}]

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use?

Answer (score 2):

Either you have an old problem with refreshing of the jqGrid pager see [Pagination problem in jqgrid with array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491963/pagination-problem-in-jqgrid-with-array-data/3495210#3495210)) or you have some new problem in jqGrid 3.8.

Try to fill al the data in one object `myData` before creating the jqGrid and to use `data: myData` jqGrid option.

If you continue have problem you should append your question with the code of your jqGrid and the JavaScript code which fill jqGrid with data.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. The link helped. I had to set the datatype: "clientside" and it worked!.