# In mvc application jqgrid is showing page 0 of

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcjqgrid

In my application all jqgrids are showing page 0 of (nothing is displayed here) on page load without any records in the grid..
  where actually it has to show page 0 of 0.

even after adding record it will show page 1 of 0 where it has to show page 1 of 1.. 
 I am not understanding what is wrong.. does anyone know what may be the problem?

I am using jqgrid 4.5.4 version and i am binding json data to the grid..

please help me with your ideas.. Thank you..[image: this is image of my grid without data]

Comment: see this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768896/jqgrid-paging-always-shows-0-of-1 .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491963/pagination-problem-in-jqgrid-with-array-data/3495210#3495210

Comment: sorry..it didnt help me..