# jqGrid pagination problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start). Pagination is not getting reflected, what could be the problem? I checked in Firefox 4.1 and IE8, but does not show jqGrid at all on chrome.

```
var filesystem=[];
$(xml).find('file').each(function(){ 
    var row={};
    row.total=$(this).attr('total');
    row.free=$(this).attr('free');
    row.used=$(this).attr('used');
    row.percentage=$(this).attr('percentage');
    filesystem.push(row);
});


$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div>')
.attr('id','diskUsageSpan')
.html('<div class="titleBlue">Configuration&gt;System&gt;Disk Usage</div>'+
        '<table id="list1"></table>'+
        '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
     '</div>')        
.appendTo('#detailTable');
```

**Updated**

```
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "clientSide",
    height: 250,
       colNames:['id','Total Space','Free Space', 'Used Space', 'Used Percentage'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, align:"right"},
           {name:'total',index:'total', width:90, align:"right"},
           {name:'free',index:'free', width:90, align:"right"},
           {name:'used',index:'used', width:90, align:"right"},
           {name:'percentage',index:'percentage', width:120, align:"right"}
       ],
       pagination:true,
       pager : '#gridpager',
       rowNum:10,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false

});



for(var i=0;i<filesystem.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,filesystem[i]);

jQuery("#list1").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: @doctrey: please look at the problem

Comment: @Tomas: I created a dataset to match jqGrid, and it loads also, but the pagination is not working. Can you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @Oleg: I followed your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491963/pagination-problem-in-jqgrid-with-array-data), but still no luck, can you look at the problem too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should call `reloadGrid` **after** the `addRowData` sage and not before.

The best way would be to use `data` parameter instead:

```
var grid = jQuery("#list1");
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: filesystem, // here!!!
    height: "auto", // it can be better if you don't need the fix hight
    colNames: ['Total Space','Free Space', 'Used Space', 'Used Percentage'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'free',index:'free', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'used',index:'used', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'percentage',index:'percentage', width:120, align:"right"}
    ],
    pager : '#gridpager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

No grid reloading is needed.

If you fill `row` for `filesystem` I would recommend you include additional `id` property in the `row` which will be used as the rowid. The value of ids of all HTML elements used on the page must be unique.

Instead of recreating of the `div#detailTable` contain like you do you can just call [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232038/jqgrid-add-new-column/4232168#4232168) for an example). Are you really need recreate the grid and not just change the grid contain? To change the grid contain you can just set `data` parameter of jqGrid with respect of `setGridParam` and call `.trigger("reloadGrid")`.

Comment: Ok I added a `ID`, but how do make it not appear in the table?

Comment: @Ricky : You are welcome! The property name must be `id` and not `ID`. You can use `localReader: {id: "ID"}` if you want to use another property name. The problem is that every `<tr>` element of the `<table>` will receive the id. The `id` will **not displayed**, but in all events like [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) or in methods like [setSelection](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) the grid rows will be identified by the rowid. You can use Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to examine the row contain and see ids.

Comment: Please check, why my id is still getting displayed, I updated my question